# app.yaml setting for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-app-engine

I have application created in CodeIgniter, I uploaded all application filse(php files). But when I browse my application from google app engine it works fine but the js,css and images files are not loaded. 
this is my app.yaml file

```
application: root_folder
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: .*
script: index.php

- url: /assets/js
static_dir: /assets/js

- url: /assets/css
static_dir: /assets/css

- url: /assets/images
static_dir: /assets/images

- url: /assets/fonts
static_dir: /assets/fonts

- url: /assets/js
static_dir: /assets/js

- url: /assets/buttons
static_dir: /assets/buttons

- url: /assets/img
static_dir: /assets/img

- url: /favicon.ico
static_files: /favicon.ico
upload: /favicon.ico
expiration: 30d
```

any can help me? thanks

Comment: perhaps put the .* handler last, so it only matches what does not match evertything else?